# How I can deal with outside commas from java-script

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, xmlhttprequest

I'm facing a problem, flask app is returning an array in this form "['Aliens vs Predator: Requiem', 'Aliens', 'Anne of Green Gables']", but when I tried to access 0 index(first index), only [ this bracket prints on "demo" id;

So I have to remove outside commas of arrays so that I will get this result: ['Aliens vs Predator: Requiem', 'Aliens', 'Anne of Green Gables'].
I didn't have any idea to do this, anybody can help me,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Declaring an Array</h2>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    
    var movies = "['Aliens vs Predator: Requiem', 'Aliens', 'Anne of Green Gables']";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = movies[0];
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: "flask app is returning an array in this form" — That's a very odd form. Can you not change the flask app so it returns JSON instead?

Answer (score 1):

Technically there no bouble quotes on the string but still solution for your question maybe is mention below.

```js
var movies = "['Aliens vs Predator: Requiem', 'Aliens', 'Anne of Green Gables']";

//will just remove start and last character from a string not from in between from a string 
const withoutFirstAndLast = movies.slice(1, -1);
console.log(withoutFirstAndLast);

//will replace all "" from a string 
const removed = movies.replaceAll('"', '');
console.log(removed);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can parse your data this way (the JSON parser doesn't like single quotes):

```js
var movies = "['Aliens vs Predator: Requiem', 'Aliens', 'Anne of Green Gables']";
let data = JSON.parse(movies.replaceAll('\'',"\""))
console.log(data[0])
```

Comment: What if one of the values in `movies` contains a single quote? Like `"['Aliens\\'']"`